# Can't connect to 127.0.0.1 on High Sierra

Tags: macos, apache, httpd.conf

I have set up localhost on High Sierra and have all of my web projects in the Sites directory. Everything works fine in that I can access my site using:

```
http://localhost/~foo/my-site
```

No problems here. However, I now require Cassandra for one of my projects and I am trying to connect to it on the default ports using:

```
127.0.0.1:9042
```

It doesn't work.  If I go to 127.0.0.1 I get:

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access / on this server.
```

I can ping 127.0.0.1 though. Any ideas on how I can get localhost to work while still using Sites?

Comment: Have you tried to turn off the firewall ? Sometimes that helped for me.

Comment: Well, maybe not turning off the firewall, but maybe allowing Cassandra through on that particular port would be good.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is forbidden, so I can't even get to localhost on 80.

Comment: Experiencing same issue on macOS Mojave